# Two ViewPager inside coordinator layout android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout

The CoordinatorLayout uses two ViewPager. The first ViewPager is inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and the second ViewPager contains contents.  Problems is on Y scrolling, the content ViewPager is overlapping the ViewPager in CollapsingToolbarLayout. The expected result must be both scrolling as one entity. Does someone face this issue. Please help am stuck on this issue for 12 hours now.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarAccountCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/accounts_storecard_background"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                app:statusBarScrim="@null"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                    <myapp.android.ui.views.WTextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
                        android:text="Store card"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:WTextView_font="medium_bold" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <myapp.android.util.WCustomViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/myAccountsCardPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <myapp.android.ui.views.WFragmentViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragmentpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```